# Problems assigning the output of a for and if else statement in R

Tags: r

When using a for and if else statement I have ran into the issue of not being able to assign the output as a vector multiple times as seen with the code in the first example. Why does the first example fail at assigning a vector to `age30output` even though it prints correctly to the console while the second example works? Is there a way to make the first example work so that the output can be assigned as a vector of `[1] NA 31 NA NA`?

Edit: In the first example I've also tried replacing the `print()` function with `return()` only for it to return the first value of the element `[1] 22` as well as the the following error message -  `Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level.`

```
ages <- c(22, 31, 26, 54)
age30s <- c(30:39)
```

First example:

```
> age30output <- for (i in 1:length(ages)) {
+     if(ages[i] %in% age30s) {
+         print(ages[i])
+     } else {
+         print(NA)
+         }
+     }
[1] NA
[1] 31
[1] NA
[1] NA
> age30output
NULL
```

Second example:

```
> ages30output <- vector(length = 4)
> age30output <- for (i in 1:length(ages)) {
+     if(ages[i] %in% age30s) {
+         ages30output[i] <- ages[i]
+     } else {
+         ages30output[i] <- NA
+         }
+     }
> ages30output
[1] NA 31 NA NA
```

Comment: There is no return value with `print`

Comment: No. According to `help('for')`, `for`, `while` and `repeat` loops always return `NULL`. Also, take a look at the `ifelse` function, I think it applies well to your usecase.

Comment: for doesn't return a value, take a look at the `apply` family if you want loops that return values, also using a loop for this task is an overkill : `ages[ages %in% age30s]` this will give you the ages that are in age30s also you could use `intersect(ages, age30s)`

Answer (score 0):

According to `?print`

> print prints its argument and returns it invisibly (via invisible(x)). It is a generic function which means that new printing methods can be easily added for new classes.